# Python: map() with partial arguments

Tags: python

I got a multi-argument function. I simplified the function to map, and here's my function to test with:

```
def _dist(I,J,X,Y):
    return abs(I-X)+abs(J-Y)
```

And in some case, I just want to hold X,Y as constant and iterate I,J over u_x and u_y, respectively. I write down something below (while SyntaxError raised)

```
new=map(_dist(,,cur.x(),cur.y()),u_x,u_y)
```

where the cur.x() and cur.y() are constant.
Anyway to do it with map()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not use a list comprehension?

```
new = [_dist(x,y,i,j) for x in ux for y in uy]
```

where `i` and `j` are your constants.

Note that this is equivalent to

```
new = map(lambda (x,y): _dist(x,y,i,j), [(x,y) for x in ux for y in uy])
```

but somewhat shorter (and probably more efficient).

---

Edit (in response to @chepner's comment) - if you want to iterate through the zipped product of `ux` and `uy` then you can do

```
new = [_dist(x,y,i,j) for (x,y) in zip(ux,uy)]
```

instead. Note the difference -

```
>> ux = [1, 2, 3]
>> uy = [4, 5, 6]
>> [(x,y) for x in ux for y in uy]

[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]

>> zip(ux, uy)

[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: You want to zip `ux` and `uy` together; your code iterates over the cartesian product of `ux` and `uy` instead.

Comment: @chepner I thought that was the intention!

Comment: `map(func, L1, L2)` is equivalent to `[func(L1[0], L2[0]), func(L1[1], L2[1]), ..., func(L1[-1], L2[-1])]`

Comment: Ah, ok - I read the phrase "iterate I,J over u_x and u_y" which suggests cartesian product to me. I ignored the code because the OP admitted that they didn't know what they were doing ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can partially apply `_dist`:

```
from functools import partial
_mapfunc = partial(_dist, X=cur.x(), Y=cur.y())
new = map(_mapfunc, u_x, u_y)
```

although Chris Taylor's list comprehension is probably more efficient.